# Laravel Artisan commands creates new files as root instead of 1000

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I currently have a nice docker setup for my laravel project

[image]

When I need to execute a php artisan command, I attache the php-fpm container to my terminal. It all works fine. except when the artisan command creates new files.

[image]

The files are created as root. To solve that i need to "chown -R 1000:1000 /application"

It's very annoying to do that everytime and was wandering if there's a way in Ubuntu or in my docker setup so that artisan creates the files as 1000 by himself and I don't need to worry about that anymore.

Comment: Files are owned by who creates them. You can change group of the files automatically with setgid but not user – the setuid bit is ignored on directories.

Comment: Yes but there has to be a way in the docker-compose file to give docker a user or something. Or in the laravel artisan service. Something I can setup so that I no longer need to chown anymore

Comment: If you are running artisan as root, that's who will own the files. You could use `sudo` to run it as a different user.

Comment: Yes but that’s not what I am asking. I want to find a way to solve the problem before it even occurs. Either in the ubuntu setup or in the docker-compose file. I am even ready to add some logic to the laravel kernel. My docker setup will be used by other people and even if for me chown is not a big deal, others might not like that. So I need to find a way to transparently deal with it. I know what the problem is, I know all the work arounds. What I am looking for is solve it in a way where php artisan commands create the files in the right user without anything else then the command itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is create a user and tell Docker to use that user for all subsequent actions, e.g.

```
# Dockerfile
...

WORKDIR /var/www

...

# create a new linux user group called 'developer' with an arbitrary group id of '1001'
RUN groupadd -g 1001 developer

# create a new user called developer and add it to this group
RUN useradd -u 1001 -g developer developer

# change the owner and group of the current working directory to developer
COPY --chown=developer:developer . /var/www

# run all subsequent processes as this user
USER developer

...

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Creating a group isn't strictly necessary but can be useful if you need to assign multiple services or users the same privileges across a single cluster or server.

If you don't assign a non-root user to your Docker containers for something like local development then it's not the end of the world but you'll encounter the problems you are having. However, in production it can be a *serious* security concern because it can enable a attacker to gain root privileges to the rest of your system.

Dockerfile reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who had same issue with laravel and sail/docker.

On installing sail for laravel application development, by default docker will only run with root user. So if you run docker/sail with sudo, the files created using php artisan will all belong to root so it will require you to set/add permission for all new files created.

To solve this issue for local development you can change the permission for the docker.sock like this:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```